# JS - store a function's arguement in a variable to use in another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So basically, I pass in a value as an argument into a function, and then I want to use the same value in another function by storing that argument as a variable. The problem is that if I define the variable inside the first function, it can only be accessed within that function. What do I do? Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        function showUser(selection) {
          var selectedOption = selection;//THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO ACCESS IN ANOTHER FUNCTION
          //Some code
        }
        function saveTime(solvedTime) {
//This is where I am using the variable
xmlhttp.open("GET","savetimes.php?q="+selectedOption+"&time="+solvedTime, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
    </script>
    <form id="session">
     <select name="sessions" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
       <option value="1">Session 1</option>
       <option value="2">Session 2</option>
     </select>
   </form>
      <br>
   <div id="timesList">
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make it global, pass it, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your variable outside the function. It will be accessible all functions in that scope. To not mutate this object with the global scope, you can wrap it with **[IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)**. Use `addEventListener` to handle the event, this is a more preferable approach to handle events. Also check in the `saveTime` if any value was selected or not before the request.

```js
(function() {

   const sessions = document.getElementById('sessions');
   let selectedOption;
   
   sessions.addEventListener('change', function() {
      selectedOption = this.value;
      console.log(selectedOption);
   });  
   
   function saveTime(solvedTime) {
      if(selectedOption) {
         xmlhttp.open("GET","savetimes.php?q="+selectedOption+"&time="+solvedTime, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
      }
   }
  
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="session">
 <select id="sessions" name="sessions">
     <option value="1">Session 1</option>
     <option value="2">Session 2</option>
 </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="timesList"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```